# DbReference with custom MongoIdentifier (MongoDB & NoRM)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, norm

I'm a new Mongo user (haven't gotten used to the name even... makes me 
laugh every time), and I have this problem (feeling mongo).

I have a class "User", with the MongoIdentifier defined like this:

```
[MongoIdentifier] 
public string Username { get; set; }
```

In another class "Role" I have a `DbReference` that looks like this:

```
public DbReference<User> Creator { get; set; }
```

This compiles well, but when I try to set the Creator like this:

```
role.Creator = new Norm.BSON.DbTypes.DbReference<User>(userOnline.Username);
```

I get the following error:

**System.FormatException: Could not find any recognizable digits.**

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution... I had to specify the type of the MongoIdentifier:

```
public DbReference<User, String> Creator { get; set; }
```

and...

```
role.Creator = new Norm.BSON.DbTypes.DbReference<User, String>(userOnline.Username);
```